# Scanning device for audio files directories takes too long in android

Tags: android, performance, android-file

I have the following code which scan a device for directories which contain mp3.
The following does the job, but unfortunately in some devices where the amount of directories is huge, it takes too long to scan.
**Is there a way to speed it up?**

```
scanDirectory(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());


private void scanDirectory(File dir) {

    File[] files = dir.listFiles();

    if( files != null ){            
        for( int i=0; i<files.length; i++ ){
            File file = files[i];
            if( file.isDirectory() ){
                if( hasAudioFile(file) ){
                    mFolders.add(file.getAbsolutePath()); // this directory has a mp3 file
                }
                scanDirectory(file);                    
            }
        }
    }
}

private boolean hasAudioFile(File dir){
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    if( files == null ){
        return false;
    }
    for( int i=0; i<files.length; i++ ){
        File file = files[i];
        if( !file.isDirectory() ){
            if( file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3") ){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I know that there is a method to scan all music files in a device which more faster([like this one)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24006096/1503155), but in my case I want the folders not the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem.

If you're loading these folders into a list, you could check the folder one level deep and see whether it contains audio, and just check it as the list is loaded - so you don't scan so many folders.

Alternatively, you could run this as a background task in a boot-service, saving the results into a database which you could update as files are added/updated/modified/removed.

Another way would be to use the method provided in your link, get a list of audio files from the MediaStore content provider, then traverse that list of files - obtain each file's parent - then add that to your list.